# AWS Lambda to delete everything from a specific folder in an S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to delete everything from a specific folder in an S3 bucket with AWS Lambda using Python. The Lambda runs successfully however, the files still exist in "folder1". There will be no sub-folder under this folder except files.

Could someone please assist? Here is the code:

```
import json
import os
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    deletefile_bucket = s3.Bucket('test_bucket')
    response = deletefile_bucket.delete_objects(
        Delete={
            'Objects': [
                {
                    'Key': 'folder1/'
                   
                },
            ],
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delete_objects()` command requires a list of object keys to delete. It does not perform wildcard operations and it does not delete the contents of subdirectories.

You will need to obtain a listing of all objects and then specifically request those objects to be deleted.

The `delete_objects()` command accepts up to 1000 objects to delete.

Comment: Thanks John. I have updated my code as above. The Lambda now runs successfully however, the files still exist in "folder1". Please note: there will be no sub-folders inside "folder1". Is there a way to delete everything from a specific folder inside an S3 bucket?

Comment: You need to specify the `Key` of every object you want to delete. You cannot specify the name of a directory -- you need to **specify every object**. (Directories do not actually exist in Amazon S3 -- they are simply part of each object's Key.)

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted and correct, if it has solved your problem.